# Can't sometimes access BIOS or Windows after startup

Tags: motherboard, bios, freeze, boot, post

Sometimes after I start up my computer it freezes in the "press <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter UEFI BIOS setting" screen and doesn't react to those buttons. The backlight on the USB keyboard is lit but it doesn't seem to bee active as <kbd>caps lock</kbd> can't be turned on.

My motherboard is Asus P8Z77-V LK. It's stand-by led is on in the start-up but DRAM led is off. This problem has occured only when cold booting and never (yet) when restarting from Windows. I have tried running memtest and no errors were found during it.

The system is also very stable after properly booting. I updated BIOS once but it was a long ago and these problems started showing up quite recently. I have tried changing the boot order for my hard drives with no effect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the same thing occur with another keyboard or if you move the keyboard to another computer (Troubleshooting 101, try to determine which part if failing. desktop/mobo, or keyboard).  Does unplugging and replugging the keyboard help (to reset the keyboard) ?

Comment: Unplugging and replugging has no effect. I unfortunately don't have another computer to test with but I could try to use another keyboard and see if the problem persists...

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember exactly what it was, but there is a setting in the BIOS in regards to FULL USB support. I had to do that. Actually sometimes I have to boot into windows 8 and then tell windows 8 I want access to the BIOS. wild stuff.

If you have a wired USB keyboard kicking around you might want to confirm you are completed locked out. Does your MB show a number when it's frozen like that? On my MB there are 4 status numbers. I always have to look in the book when things go crazy.

Good luck!